# File Upload button not formatting

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style a "file upload" button. See pic. I've used a file upload - same HTML as below - and that has a textbox around it but I can't understand why the exact same HTML doesn't produce that textbox.

```
<div class="content style4 featured center-block">
    <div class="container 75%">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row 50%">
                <div class="6u">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="cold_email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                    <input type="file" name="cold_resume" id="resume">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u">
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" /></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

here is the code for another file input. Why does this look different (has a border around it)? See pic.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            <input type="file" name="resume">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
    </form>
```

[image]

Picture:

[image]

Comment: you cannot style a file input in a normal manner with CSS, you'll need to look at triggering the file input + hiding it with javascript if you want bootstrap styling

Comment: as @DavidNguyen mentioned, you'll have to do something outside the normal. This is because the file button is a "special" part of the file upload input and differs between browsers

Comment: Fair enough, I'm curious as to why another file upload is rendering differently. See pic.